# Accessing HTTP resource on HTTPS IIS Site with ARR Proxy Setting

Tags: iis, https

I have a https site on IIS requesting resources from a http-only API server(Tomcat). There is no SSL certificate in the backend server. I try to avoid the browser error.

I encountered failure for requesting https/http resources from a https site.

1. I would like to know if there is any reverse proxy setting with ARR that can resolve this problem?
2. Is it necessary for the API server has HTTPS?

For instance,

The client application url : https://www.example.com/login

The requesting resource: https://www.example.com:8080/api/login

The working api: http://www.example.com:8080/api/login

I have tried adding the following,but not working

```
<rule name="web" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example.com$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://example.com/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

1. ARR can solve this problem.
2. It is no necessary for api server has HTTPS.

Since I only have IIS and no tomcat server, I cannot completely restore your environment, but most of the settings are on the ARR server, so I can give you a reference.

I add two server into server farm and enable URL rewrite at server level. The URL rewrite rule can rewrite https://test2.com/b.html to http://server1IP/api/b.html or http://server2IP/api/b.html.

```
 <rule name="ARR_farm_loadbalance" enabled="true" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="*" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://farm/api/{R:0}" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="On" />
                </conditions>
  </rule>
```

It works very well.

[image]

If you want to use HTTPS in api server, change it in URL rewrite module.
[image]